# materials in fbx export

Tags: export

I want to export a scene from Blender in fbx format for use with Unreal game engine. For materials the objects have baked texture maps, which would be presented in Unreal as such. Are texture images packed into a fbx file, or does the file only contain instructions for loading an image file? What is the best procedure for fbx exports of objects with texture images? Should the images be packed into the .blend, and does it matter if the Blender scene is using Cycles or Blender Render Engine when exporting?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've been figuring this out simply by doing it. For stationary objects, the only export setting that may be tricky might be that for Smoothing- Edge, Face, or Normals Only.

Comment: Please see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures FBX or other file formats don't really export materials or try to do so. Materials should be created in Unreal engie, what you need are UVs, which should be preserved be default, and textures saved as standalone image files, so they can be used in engine.

Answer (score 1):

The FBX format exported by Blender does not have images included internally, even if you "pack" the images (for including them in the `.blend` save file).  Your best bet after baking your textures is to save them to real files on disk, so the exported FBX can reference them by name.

Answer (score 0):

internal render or cycles no matter. maximum you take material slots and textures , UE can create simple mat for you, but also very simple create it manual.
for recognition complicated blender material need to do more stuff by null in UE.